# only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices when using EvolutionaryFS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm using GeneticAlgorithm to select the features.

So I used EvolutionaryFS library

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
from EvolutionaryFS import GeneticAlgorithmFS

seed = 0
np.random.seed(seed)

df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/RT_predict/Urine_DnS/Dataset/0607/0607Dragon_0607edit.csv")

dataset = df.values
X = dataset[:,0:-1]
Y = dataset[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

input_dim = X.shape[1]

def build_model(n1_neurons=1000, n2_neurons=500):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_dim))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n1_neurons, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n2_neurons, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    return model

data_dict={0:{'x_train':X_train,'y_train':Y_train,'x_test':X_test,'y_test':Y_test}}
columns_list=list(df.columns)

model_object=build_model
evoObj=GeneticAlgorithmFS(model=model_object,data_dict=data_dict,cost_function='mean_squared_error',average='',cost_function_improvement='decrease',columns_list=columns_list,generations=100,population=50,prob_crossover=0.9,prob_mutation=0.1,run_time=60000)
best_columns=evoObj.GetBestFeatures()
print(best_columns)
```

and I got error like this:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-20-33e6ab735f97> in <module>()
     47 model_object=build_model
     48 evoObj=GeneticAlgorithmFS(model=model_object,data_dict=data_dict,cost_function='mean_squared_error',average='',cost_function_improvement='decrease',columns_list=columns_list,generations=100,population=50,prob_crossover=0.9,prob_mutation=0.1,run_time=60000)
---> 49 best_columns=evoObj.GetBestFeatures()
     50 print(best_columns)

2 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/EvolutionaryFS.py in
_getCost(self, population_array)
     95         for i in self.data_dict.keys():
     96
---> 97             x_train=self.data_dict[i]['x_train'][columns_list]
     98             y_train=self.data_dict[i]['y_train']
     99

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

### I think there is a problem about dataset, but I can't solve this problem.

Edited at July 6th.

I did advise that StatguyUser suggested, and I got this error message when I inactive

```
best_columns=evoObj.GetBestFeatures()
print(best_columns)
```

```
['Unnamed: 0', 'MW', 'Sv', 'Se', 'Sp', ..., 'ALOGP', 'Normalized RT (min)']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a63bc4c481bb> in <module>()
     46 print(columns_list)
     47 
---> 48 print(data_dict[0]['x_train'][columns_list].shape)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Edited at July 26th.

I did advise that StatguyUser suggested, but it not works.

My error message is like this

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '271', '272', '273', '274', '275', '276', '277', '278', '279', '280', '281', '282', '283', '284', '285', '286', '287', '288', '289', '290', '291', '292', '293', '294', '295', '296', '297', '298', '299', '300', '301', '302', '303', '304', '305', '306', '307', '308', '309', '310', '311', '312', '313', '314', '315', '316', '317', '318', '319', '320', '321', '322', '323', '324', '325', '326', '327', '328', '329', '330', '331', '332', '333', '334', '335', '336', '337', '338', '339', '340', '341', '342', '343', '344', '345', '346', '347', '348', '349', '350', '351', '352', '353', '354', '355', '356', '357', '358', '359', '360', '361', '362', '363', '364', '365', '366', '367', '368', '369', '370', '371', '372', '373', '374', '375', '376', '377', '378', '379', '380', '381', '382', '383', '384', '385', '386', '387', '388', '389', '390', '391', '392', '393', '394', '395', '396', '397', '398', '399', '400', '401', '402', '403', '404', '405', '406', '407', '408', '409', '410', '411', '412', '413', '414', '415', '416', '417', '418', '419', '420', '421', '422', '423', '424', '425', '426', '427', '428', '429', '430', '431', '432', '433', '434', '435', '436', '437', '438', '439', '440', '441', '442', '443', '444', '445', '446', '447', '448', '449', '450', '451', '452', '453', '454', '455', '456', '457', '458', '459', '460', '461', '462', '463', '464', '465', '466', '467', '468', '469', '470', '471', '472', '473', '474', '475', '476', '477', '478', '479', '480', '481', '482', '483', '484', '485', '486', '487', '488', '489', '490', '491', '492', '493', '494', '495', '496', '497', '498', '499', '500', '501', '502', '503', '504', '505', '506', '507', '508', '509', '510', '511', '512', '513', '514', '515', '516', '517', '518', '519', '520', '521', '522', '523', '524', '525', '526', '527', '528', '529', '530', '531', '532', '533', '534', '535', '536', '537', '538', '539', '540', '541', '542', '543', '544', '545', '546', '547', '548', '549', '550', '551', '552', '553', '554', '555', '556', '557', '558', '559', '560', '561', '562', '563', '564', '565', '566', '567', '568', '569', '570', '571', '572', '573', '574', '575', '576', '577', '578', '579', '580', '581', '582', '583', '584', '585', '586', '587', '588', '589', '590', '591', '592', '593', '594', '595', '596', '597', '598', '599', '600', '601', '602', '603', '604', '605', '606', '607', '608', '609', '610', '611', '612', '613', '614', '615', '616', '617', '618', '619', '620', '621', '622', '623', '624', '625', '626', '627', '628', '629', '630', '631', '632', '633', '634', '635', '636', '637', '638', '639', '640', '641', '642', '643', '644', '645', '646', '647', '648', '649', '650', '651', '652', '653', '654', '655', '656', '657', '658', '659', '660', '661', '662', '663', '664', '665', '666', '667', '668', '669', '670', '671', '672', '673', '674', '675', '676', '677', '678', '679', '680', '681', '682', '683', '684', '685', '686', '687', '688', '689', '690', '691', '692', '693', '694', '695', '696', '697', '698', '699', '700', '701', '702', '703', '704', '705', '706', '707', '708', '709', '710', '711', '712', '713', '714', '715', '716', '717', '718', '719', '720', '721', '722', '723', '724', '725', '726', '727', '728', '729', '730', '731', '732', '733', '734', '735', '736', '737', '738', '739', '740', '741', '742', '743', '744', '745', '746', '747', '748', '749', '750', '751', '752', '753', '754', '755', '756', '757', '758', '759', '760', '761', '762', '763', '764', '765', '766', '767', '768', '769', '770', '771', '772', '773', '774', '775', '776', '777', '778', '779', '780', '781', '782', '783', '784', '785', '786', '787', '788', '789', '790', '791', '792', '793', '794', '795', '796', '797', '798', '799', '800', '801', '802', '803', '804', '805', '806', '807', '808', '809', '810', '811', '812', '813', '814', '815', '816', '817', '818', '819', '820', '821', '822', '823', '824', '825', '826', '827', '828', '829', '830', '831', '832', '833', '834', '835', '836', '837', '838', '839', '840', '841', '842', '843', '844', '845', '846', '847', '848', '849', '850', '851', '852', '853', '854', '855', '856', '857', '858', '859', '860', '861', '862', '863', '864', '865', '866', '867', '868', '869', '870', '871', '872', '873', '874', '875', '876', '877', '878', '879', '880', '881', '882', '883', '884', '885', '886', '887', '888', '889', '890', '891', '892', '893', '894', '895', '896', '897', '898', '899', '900', '901', '902', '903', '904', '905', '906', '907', '908', '909', '910', '911', '912', '913', '914', '915', '916', '917', '918', '919', '920', '921', '922', '923', '924', '925', '926', '927', '928', '929', '930', '931', '932', '933', '934', '935', '936', '937', '938', '939', '940', '941', '942', '943', '944', '945', '946', '947', '948', '949', '950', '951', '952', '953', '954', '955', '956', '957', '958', '959', '960', '961', '962', '963', '964', '965', '966', '967', '968', '969', '970', '971', '972', '973', '974', '975', '976', '977', '978', '979', '980', '981', '982', '983', '984', '985', '986', '987', '988', '989', '990', '991', '992', '993', '994', '995', '996', '997', '998', '999', '1000', '1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006', '1007', '1008', '1009', '1010', '1011', '1012', '1013', '1014', '1015', '1016', '1017', '1018', '1019', '1020', '1021', '1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1031', '1032', '1033', '1034', '1035', '1036', '1037', '1038', '1039', '1040', '1041', '1042', '1043', '1044', '1045', '1046', '1047', '1048', '1049', '1050', '1051', '1052', '1053', '1054', '1055', '1056', '1057', '1058', '1059', '1060', '1061', '1062', '1063', '1064', '1065', '1066', '1067', '1068', '1069', '1070', '1071', '1072', '1073', '1074', '1075', '1076', '1077', '1078', '1079', '1080', '1081', '1082', '1083', '1084', '1085', '1086', '1087', '1088', '1089', '1090', '1091', '1092', '1093', '1094', '1095', '1096', '1097', '1098', '1099', '1100', '1101', '1102', '1103', '1104', '1105', '1106', '1107', '1108', '1109', '1110', '1111', '1112', '1113', '1114', '1115', '1116', '1117', '1118', '1119', '1120', '1121', '1122', '1123', '1124', '1125', '1126', '1127', '1128', '1129', '1130', '1131', '1132', '1133', '1134', '1135', '1136', '1137', '1138', '1139', '1140', '1141', '1142', '1143', '1144', '1145', '1146', '1147', '1148', '1149', '1150', '1151', '1152', '1153', '1154', '1155', '1156', '1157', '1158', '1159', '1160', '1161', '1162', '1163', '1164', '1165', '1166', '1167', '1168', '1169', '1170', '1171', '1172', '1173', '1174', '1175', '1176', '1177', '1178', '1179', '1180', '1181', '1182', '1183', '1184', '1185', '1186', '1187', '1188', '1189', '1190', '1191', '1192', '1193', '1194', '1195', '1196', '1197', '1198', '1199', '1200', '1201', '1202', '1203', '1204', '1205', '1206', '1207', '1208', '1209', '1210', '1211', '1212', '1213', '1214', '1215', '1216', '1217', '1218', '1219', '1220', '1221', '1222', '1223', '1224', '1225', '1226', '1227', '1228', '1229', '1230', '1231', '1232', '1233', '1234', '1235', '1236', '1237', '1238', '1239', '1240', '1241', '1242', '1243', '1244', '1245', '1246', '1247', '1248', '1249', '1250', '1251', '1252', '1253', '1254', '1255', '1256', '1257', '1258', '1259', '1260', '1261', '1262', '1263', '1264', '1265', '1266', '1267', '1268', '1269', '1270', '1271', '1272', '1273', '1274', '1275', '1276', '1277', '1278', '1279', '1280', '1281', '1282', '1283', '1284', '1285', '1286', '1287', '1288', '1289', '1290', '1291', '1292', '1293', '1294', '1295', '1296', '1297', '1298', '1299', '1300', '1301', '1302', '1303', '1304', '1305', '1306', '1307', '1308', '1309', '1310', '1311', '1312', '1313', '1314', '1315', '1316', '1317', '1318', '1319', '1320', '1321', '1322', '1323', '1324', '1325', '1326', '1327', '1328', '1329', '1330', '1331', '1332', '1333', '1334', '1335', '1336', '1337', '1338', '1339', '1340', '1341', '1342', '1343', '1344', '1345', '1346', '1347', '1348', '1349', '1350', '1351', '1352', '1353', '1354', '1355', '1356', '1357', '1358', '1359', '1360', '1361', '1362', '1363', '1364', '1365', '1366', '1367', '1368', '1369', '1370', '1371', '1372', '1373', '1374', '1375', '1376', '1377', '1378', '1379', '1380', '1381', '1382', '1383', '1384', '1385', '1386', '1387', '1388', '1389', '1390', '1391', '1392', '1393', '1394', '1395', '1396', '1397', '1398', '1399', '1400', '1401', '1402', '1403', '1404', '1405', '1406', '1407', '1408', '1409', '1410', '1411', '1412', '1413', '1414', '1415', '1416', '1417', '1418', '1419', '1420', '1421', '1422', '1423', '1424', '1425', '1426', '1427', '1428', '1429', '1430', '1431', '1432', '1433', '1434', '1435', '1436', '1437', '1438', '1439', '1440', '1441', '1442', '1443', '1444', '1445', '1446', '1447', '1448', '1449', '1450', '1451', '1452', '1453', '1454', '1455', '1456', '1457', '1458', '1459', '1460', '1461', '1462', '1463', '1464', '1465', '1466', '1467', '1468', '1469', '1470', '1471', '1472', '1473', '1474', '1475', '1476', '1477', '1478', '1479', '1480', '1481', '1482', '1483', '1484', '1485', '1486', '1487', '1488', '1489', '1490', '1491', '1492', '1493', '1494', '1495', '1496', '1497', '1498', '1499', '1500', '1501', '1502', '1503', '1504', '1505', '1506', '1507', '1508', '1509', '1510', '1511', '1512', '1513', '1514', '1515', '1516', '1517', '1518', '1519', '1520', '1521', '1522', '1523', '1524', '1525', '1526', '1527', '1528', '1529', '1530', '1531', '1532', '1533', '1534', '1535', '1536', '1537', '1538', '1539', '1540', '1541', '1542', '1543', '1544', '1545', '1546', '1547', '1548', '1549', '1550', '1551', '1552', '1553', '1554', '1555', '1556', '1557', '1558', '1559', '1560', '1561', '1562', '1563', '1564', '1565', '1566', '1567', '1568', '1569', '1570', '1571', '1572', '1573', '1574', '1575', '1576', '1577', '1578', '1579', '1580', '1581', '1582', '1583', '1584', '1585', '1586', '1587', '1588', '1589', '1590', '1591', '1592', '1593', '1594', '1595', '1596', '1597', '1598', '1599', '1600', '1601', '1602', '1603', '1604', '1605', '1606', '1607', '1608', '1609', '1610', '1611', '1612', '1613', '1614', '1615', '1616', '1617', '1618', '1619', '1620', '1621', '1622', '1623', '1624', '1625', '1626', '1627', '1628', '1629', '1630', '1631', '1632', '1633', '1634', '1635', '1636', '1637', '1638', '1639', '1640', '1641', '1642', '1643', '1644', '1645', '1646', '1647', '1648', '1649', '1650', '1651', '1652', '1653', '1654', '1655', '1656', '1657', '1658', '1659', '1660', '1661', '1662', '1663', '1664', '1665', '1666', '1667', '1668', '1669', '1670', '1671', '1672', '1673', '1674', '1675', '1676', '1677', '1678', '1679', '1680', '1681', '1682', '1683', '1684', '1685', '1686', '1687', '1688', '1689', '1690', '1691', '1692', '1693', '1694', '1695', '1696', '1697', '1698', '1699', '1700', '1701', '1702', '1703', '1704', '1705', '1706', '1707', '1708', '1709', '1710', '1711', '1712', '1713', '1714', '1715', '1716', '1717', '1718', '1719', '1720', '1721', '1722', '1723', '1724', '1725', '1726', '1727', '1728', '1729', '1730', '1731', '1732', '1733', '1734', '1735', '1736', '1737', '1738', '1739', '1740', '1741', '1742', '1743', '1744', '1745', '1746', '1747', '1748', '1749', '1750', '1751', '1752', '1753', '1754', '1755', '1756', '1757', '1758', '1759', '1760', '1761', '1762', '1763', '1764', '1765', '1766', '1767', '1768', '1769', '1770', '1771', '1772', '1773', '1774', '1775', '1776', '1777', '1778', '1779', '1780', '1781', '1782', '1783', '1784', '1785', '1786', '1787', '1788', '1789', '1790', '1791', '1792', '1793', '1794', '1795', '1796', '1797', '1798', '1799', '1800', '1801', '1802', '1803', '1804', '1805', '1806', '1807', '1808', '1809', '1810', '1811', '1812', '1813', '1814', '1815', '1816', '1817', '1818', '1819', '1820', '1821', '1822', '1823', '1824', '1825', '1826', '1827', '1828', '1829', '1830', '1831', '1832', '1833', '1834', '1835', '1836', '1837', '1838', '1839', '1840', '1841', '1842', '1843', '1844', '1845', '1846', '1847', '1848', '1849', '1850', '1851', '1852', '1853', '1854', '1855', '1856', '1857', '1858', '1859', '1860', '1861', '1862', '1863', '1864', '1865', '1866', '1867', '1868', '1869', '1870', '1871', '1872']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-16-03f83ec536c1> in <module>()
     46 print(columns_list)
     47 
---> 48 print(data_dict[0]['x_train'][columns_list].shape)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why you left this link

Comment: Did you try reading it? Do you see how it explains why you are expected to post complete errors? Do you understand how the error message you have posted is not complete, following the examples there?

Comment: How can I post complete error?

Comment: Copy and past all lines in the backtrace it into your question.

Comment: I did that. Is there are different way???

Comment: A full backtrace shows many line all the way back to the first function on the call stack in the chain of function calls.

Comment: Like your edit?

Comment: I am author of EvolutionaryFS and will like to help. Can you try these two commands and print the log in your question after editing your question? 1) `print(columns_list)` and 2) `print(data_dict[0]['x_train'][columns_list].shape)`

Comment: Really? I want to contact you but i don't know how to so I make this post. I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue as it seems is because of column name with special characters that pandas is unable to recognize.

1. Rename column names for `'Unnamed: 0'` , both in pandas data frame and Python list. This might not be causing issue, but it's best practice.
2. **Real issue** appears to be column names with special characters. To solve this, replace all special characters such as round brackets `(`, `)`, percentage `%`, backward and forward slash `\`, `/`, square bracket `[`, `]`  from the names of your pandas data frame columns. If you need any special character, then only use space   or underscore`_` in both your pandas column names and Python list which has these column names. This should solve your issue.

Let me know if you are still facing this issue.

Edit: It appears that issue is because of x_train is numpy matrix and not dataframe

Comment: Oh, really? I'm busy of different kind of stuff, so this reply is late. I'll try and comment about this issue later.

Comment: The problem not solved even I switch the pandas column names. What should I do? I changed pandas column name like recent edit, but nothing solved.  How can I solve this exhaustive problem????

Comment: *try step by step and tell me in which steps you are getting error and where you are not getting error, along with error detail for each step* `step 1:` print(data_dict.keys())  `step 2:` print(data_dict[0])  `step 3:` print(data_dict[0]['x_train']) `step 4:` print(data_dict[0]['x_train'][columns_list]) `step 5:` print(data_dict[0]['x_train'][columns_list].shape) . **Add print result only for error steps.** for example: step 1: no error; step2: error message details... and so ono.

Comment: step1: no error, step2: no error, step3: no error, step4: ```IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a71c9f15b627> in <module>()
     44 #print(best_columns)
     45 
---> 46 print(data_dict[0]['x_train'][columns_list])
     47 
     48 #print(data_dict[0]['x_train'][columns_list].shape)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices```